# How to use X-Forwarded-Proto in plone and still let VHM mapping direct to the right root

Tags: plone, zope, rewriting

I am running behind a CDN that turns my https request into http and sets X-Forwarded-Proto.

I know in nginx I can create a rule that rewrites my request as
`localhost:8080/VirtualRequestBase/https/realsite.com:80/VirtualHostRoot/siteroot` so that urls come out right.

However I have a zope setup where I keep many sites and I don't want to have to change the nginx config every time I add a new one. I normally use the VHM mappings tab to map domains to siteroots, however it will ignore the VirtualHostBase directive in the path. In addition you can mix the two styles of VHM, ie set `localhost:8080/VirtualRequestBase/https/realsite.com:80/` and expect it use the mappings.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is still Nginx sitting between CDN and Plone? I think you can create a generic rules for Nginx with string substituions. If not then Nginx supports Lua scripting.